# Column and rows in Mapbox API tiles

Tags: android, maps, mapbox

Just started working on a new mobile application in Fusetools. The problem I occurred on is with Mapbox API. Mapbox offers a map tiles which you can set with {zoom}/{x}/{y} parameter in URL.

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/512/{zoom}/{x}/{y}?access_token=token
```

[Example](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/512/16/36120/23866?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZ3JhZGJhIiwiYSI6ImNpcHNxemMzaDAwMXppOG5vZ3kzMGR6OXcifQ.XtZxXwz0d44MwCrAJT8gHA).

This is what I currently have:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
|                      |                   |                |
|   16/36120/23866     |    16/36121/23866 |  16/36122/23866|
|                      |                   |                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                      |                   |                |
|   16/?/?             |   16/?/?          |  16/?/?        |
|                      |                   |                |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

First row: [16/36120/23866](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/512/16/36120/23866?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZ3JhZGJhIiwiYSI6ImNpcHNxemMzaDAwMXppOG5vZ3kzMGR6OXcifQ.XtZxXwz0d44MwCrAJT8gHA) / [16/36121/23866](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/512/16/36121/23866?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZ3JhZGJhIiwiYSI6ImNpcHNxemMzaDAwMXppOG5vZ3kzMGR6OXcifQ.XtZxXwz0d44MwCrAJT8gHA) / [16/36122/23866](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/512/16/36122/23866?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZ3JhZGJhIiwiYSI6ImNpcHNxemMzaDAwMXppOG5vZ3kzMGR6OXcifQ.XtZxXwz0d44MwCrAJT8gHA)

Second row: How to tile them properly so the map don't appear broken as seen [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9fx4.png). White lines shows where the map is broken. What would be appropriate X and Y so the map looks continuously as in first row?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mapbox Android SDK has a debug mode, [cycleDebugOptions](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/511801c17ab2dd47b11a84c6c23ed564dad04c29/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/NativeMapView.java#L408), that shows the tile info.

So the answer is 16/36122/23867.  Be certain to check the [Mapbox TOS](https://www.mapbox.com/tos/) regarding stiching and tiling by yourself.

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, it took me whole day and I still couldn't properly position the tiles. Thank you very much for details response. I'll read the TOS :) Also, never tried Mapbox Android SDK but seems I should. <3